# Match values of records with Column headers, to determine values in Python Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe having some premium prices and Strikes as below

Below is a sample dataset represented in CSV

```
    TimeStamp       230PE       235CE       235PE       240CE       P/S C/S PutPrem     CallPrem
01/04/2016 07:04    7,731040352 10,75210291 9,802974229 8,00003216  235 240 9,802974229 8,00003216
01/04/2016 07:11    7,731040352 10,75210291 9,802974229 8,00003216  235 240 9,802974229 8,00003216
01/04/2016 07:14    8,376613441 10,6956091  9,871715249 8,477475891 235 240 9,871715249 8,477475891
01/04/2016 07:21    8,376613441 10,6956091  9,871715249 8,477475891 235 240 9,871715249 8,477475891
01/04/2016 07:24    7,539026197 10,88459752 9,81295159  7,934973889 235 240 9,81295159  7,934973889
01/04/2016 07:31    7,539026197 10,88459752 9,81295159  7,934973889 235 240 9,81295159  7,934973889
01/04/2016 07:34    7,186339187 10,65619385 9,316327371 8,717498947 235 240 9,316327371 8,717498947
```

Currently my dataframe in Python needs to be populated with values in PutPrem and CallPrem all others are populated.

This value at PutPrem/CallPrem is identified by the Value at column P/S or C/S

So for the first record

P/S is 235

```
Thus value of Put Prem-> Value of "235PE" during the same timestamp
                      -> Value of (Column 4, Row 2)
                      -> 9.8029
```

In order to achieve this, I was thinking to map each value at P/S or C/S append it with "PE" or "CE" and find the resultant matching column between the Premiums Available

Thereafter I can just refer to the value at (ColNum,RowNum), as the RowNum would be always the current record.

I am using .columns.get_loc to match the column number

The below works fine while fetching column number of one particular record

```
PutPremColNum[0]=df.columns.get_loc(df['PutStrike'][x].astype(str) + "PE" )
```

Where x is the record number

However I want this to be vectorized so that I can calculate the desired column number for all the records together

Some thing like this:

```
PutPremColNum=df.columns.get_loc(df['PutStrike'].astype(str) + "PE" )
CallPremColNum=df.columns.get_loc(df['CallStrike'].astype(str) + "CE" )
```

Please let me know if the question is not clear.

I achieve the same using MATCH function in excel
Please suggest an alternative solution/approach if possible

Comment: I don't mean to be rude, but this is very hard to follow for me. Perhaps it is for other viewers as well. Maybe you could edit your post to be more of a: "Here is my problem, here is what I want" format?

Comment: Have simpliefied it @MattR